# Can't find SQL column in android project

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse

I have two classes:

Database class:

```
package com.qstra.soamazingtodoapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; // used for logging database
                                                    // version changes

    // Field Names:
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

    public static final String KEY_HOUR = "hour";
    public static final String KEY_MINUTE = "minute";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TASK,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_HOUR, KEY_MINUTE };

    // Column Numbers for each Field Name:
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
    public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
    public static final int COL_DATE = 2;
    public static final int COL_HOUR = 3;
    public static final int COL_MINUTE = 4;

    // DataBase info:
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbToDo";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainToDo";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; // The version number must be
                                                    // incremented each time a
                                                    // change to DB structure
                                                    // occurs.

    // SQL statement to create database
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TASK
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT" + KEY_HOUR + " TEXT"
            + KEY_MINUTE + " TEXT" + ");";

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Open the database connection.
    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close the database connection.
    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
    public long insertRow(String task, String date, String hour, String minute) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HOUR, hour);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MINUTE, minute);

        // Insert the data into the database.
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    // Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    // Return all data in the database.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date, String hour, String minute) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
        newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        newValues.put(KEY_HOUR, hour);
        newValues.put(KEY_MINUTE, minute);

        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version "
                    + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity class:

```
package com.qstra.soamazingtodoapp;


import com.qstratwo.soamazingtodoapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    DBAdapter myDb;
    EditText etTasks;
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    int hour_x;
    int minute_x;
    String string_hour_x, string_minute_x="None";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etTasks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        openDB();
        listViewItemClick();
        listViewItemLongClick();
        populateListView();
    //  setNotification();

    }

    @Override 
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int idD){
        if (idD== DIALOG_ID){
            return new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, kTimePickerListener, hour_x,minute_x, false);
        }
        return null;

    }
    protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                        hour_x=hourOfDay;
                        minute_x=minute;


                    string_hour_x = Integer.toString(hour_x);
                     string_minute_x = Integer.toString(minute_x);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, hour_x+" : "+ minute_x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            };



    public void setNotification(View v) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);

    }







    private void openDB() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();    
    }

    public void onClick_AddTask (View v) {

        today.setToNow();
        String  timestamp = today.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s");
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(etTasks.getText().toString())) {

            myDb.insertRow(etTasks.getText().toString(),timestamp,string_hour_x, string_minute_x); 

    }
        populateListView();


        }




    private void populateListView() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
        String[] fromFieldNames=new String[] {
                DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_TASK };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {
                R.id.textViewItemNumber, R.id.textViewItemTasks};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTask);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


    }

    private void updateTask(long id){
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(id);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String task = etTasks.getText().toString(); // POBIERANIE Z TEXTFIELD 
            today.setToNow();
            String date = today.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m");

//          String string_minute_x= Integer.toString(minute_x);
//          String string_houte_x=Integer.toString(hour_x);

            myDb.updateRow(id, task, date, string_hour_x, string_minute_x  );

        }
        cursor.close();

    }public void onClick_DeleteTasks(View v) {
        myDb.deleteAll();
        populateListView(); 
    }
    public void onClick_AppClose(View v) {
         moveTaskToBack(true); 
         MainActivity.this.finish();
    }

    public void listViewItemLongClick(){

        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTask);
        myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myDb.deleteRow(id); 
                populateListView();
                return false;

            }




        });

        }





    private void listViewItemClick(){
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTask); 
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long id) {
                updateTask(id); 
                populateListView();
                displayToast(id);

            }

        });
    }

    private void displayToast(long id){
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(id); 
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            long idDB = cursor.getLong(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID); 
            String task = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_TASK);
            String date = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);

            String message = "ID: " + idDB + "\n" + "Task: "  + task + "\n" + "Date: " + date;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

(getting id and text from texfield to database works fine but..)

I'm trying to get hour and minutes values from TimePickerDialog and insert in to database but it seems not working.

Screen shot from log cat:

[image: i.imgur.com/srQMgZr.png]

Why can't it see column named 'hour'?

Comment: your image link does not work. also, it'd be better if you pasted all the relevant code lines here instead of redirecting us to an external site

Answer (score 0):

Add commas in your statement to create database

```
// SQL statement to create database
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TASK
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_HOUR + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MINUTE + " TEXT" + ")";
```